# insert in same table avoid duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my sql statement

```
INSERT INTO tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc (
    [FK_ReportID],
    [UserID],
    [FilterExpression],
    [DateFilterValues],
    [IsCustomReport]
    )
SELECT [FK_ReportID],
    @UserId,
    [FilterExpression],
    [DateFilterValues],
    [IsCustomReport]
FROM tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc
WHERE UserID = @AssignedUserID
```

there is condition of UserID

it is basically inserting all the records in same records of a particular user for another user

i have to check if the particular filter is exist for new user then dont insert

case

how can i do that

```
[FK_ReportID]  user_id
1                   100
2                   100
3                   100
1                   101
```

now i want to insert all records of userid 100 to same table for userid 101, but as report id 1 is already there in table for 101 so it should insert only records for 2,3,4

how should we restrict that

Thank You

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You also have *very* strange formatting rules for your INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
SELECT 
    [FK_ReportID]
    ,@UserId
    ,[FilterExpression]
    ,[DateFilterValues]
    ,[IsCustomReport]
FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc m
WHERE   UserID = @AssignedUserID
AND     NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT  1 
        FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc s 
        WHERE   m.[FK_ReportID] = s.[FK_ReportID] 
        AND     s.UserID = @UserID
    )
```

Seeing as you are using SQL Server 2008, have you tried using [EXCEPT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Something like

```
SELECT 
    [FK_ReportID]
    ,@UserId
    ,[FilterExpression]
    ,[DateFilterValues]
    ,[IsCustomReport]
FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc m
WHERE   UserID = @AssignedUserID
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    [FK_ReportID]
    ,@UserId
    ,[FilterExpression]
    ,[DateFilterValues]
    ,[IsCustomReport]
FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc m
WHERE   UserID = @UserId
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use Except:

```
INSERT  INTO tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc
        ( [FK_ReportID],
          [UserID],
          [FilterExpression],
          [DateFilterValues],
          [IsCustomReport]

        )
        SELECT  [FK_ReportID],
                @UserId,
                [FilterExpression],
                [DateFilterValues],
                [IsCustomReport]
        FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc
        WHERE   UserID = @AssignedUserID
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  [FK_ReportID],
                UserId,
                [FilterExpression],
                [DateFilterValues],
                [IsCustomReport]
        FROM    tblRB_ReportFilterUserAssoc
        WHERE UserID = @UserId
```